# Send an email from HTML / Java script

Tags: javascript, html, html-email

I have a simple html page which should take the input from text box and send that as an email.

```
function getData()
{    var txt=document.getElementById("result").value;    }

<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="result" size="20">
<input type="button"  onclick="getData()"> 
</form>
</body>
```

Now i need to send the value of txt as email. Whats the easiest way to achieve that? I am familiar with Java/ Java script. I have no hands on PHP.

Comment: You can't do this in JavaScript alone.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two very different languages.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links

Comment: Yes.. I know java and java script both

Comment: You could try something along the lines of `<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post">` This DOES have drawbacks, though: You can't control the layout of the email and the email basically gets sent using the visitor's email address. Best to send the form to your server and have it send the email.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an email using client-side JavaScript.

You will need to submit the form to a server side script which can send the mail for you.

This is not too difficult using PHP, so I urge you to read up on it. Here's a good link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595

```
<form action="myscript.php">
  <input type="text" name="message" size="20">
  <input type="submit" value="Send mail""> 
</form>
```

Then in myscript.php:

```
<?
  $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$message);
?>
```